# .NET6 unmanaged memory seems not released in Docker Container that runs on AWS EC2

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a worker application which will call c++ function as the main working task, the major computing power and memory consumption is expected to be in the unmanaged code. The worker has an infinite loop to fetch tasks from Redis and execute. While I have followed instructions online to release the native memory in the native code, the memory behavior of my code is quite different when executing on docker container with a limit of memory at 2GiB which runs on AWS EC2 and on a windows machine with 32GB RAM.

For the container, I am monitoring with the AWS CloudWatch. Same load is sent multiple times, it appears that the memory usage will keep increasing until it reaches a stable state **and it will not drop when there is no job running!!** [memory utilization in AWS container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebfjc.jpg)

On the windows machine, the memory usage is much less, and it will drop to a level close to the initial state when there is no more load[Visual studio diagnostic tools Process Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDVPV.png)

The  `GC.GetTotalMemory(false)` shows the total memory of GC never goes above 50MB on both platforms. I understand this comparison may not be fair with different platforms,different available RAMs and the type of memory I am looking at seems also different(the AWS CloudWatch seems reporting the physical memory and the VS diagntictic tool is giving the private bytes), **I am more curious about what could be happening in the linux container?** It is not likely to be a memory leak in the native code to me because it remains stable like forever instead of keeps growing until reaches OOM (I do see OOM in production once though, that's why I start looking at this problem). It seems to me more like those memory are not released until .NET(or the OS?) finds it has to do so.

Appreciate if anybody could give any insight about what's happening and why the difference between Linux container and Windows!

Comment: Very interesting, so when you run the same app in an windows VM, are you running it with .NET installed on the VM or as a self-contained app?

Comment: I am directly running on my windows PC with .net SDK installed

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is down to how memory is reported by Docker running in Linux.

> On Linux, Kubernetes uses Docker to run our application. Docker limits memory usage via a cgroup. Cgroup memory limits (and usage figures) include the file cache.

Look there for a good explanation of how memory is reported in Linux vs Windows, https://www.gresearch.co.uk/blog/article/taking-out-the-garbage-fixing-a-garbage-collection-issue-for-docker-on-net/

Comment: Hi Ricky, thank you for this information. It indeed can explain the behavior in Linux, looks like the way I should go! However, it is just that my application does not involve many file r/w operations, could it be anything else cached in the Cgroup?   BTW,  in Linux the value reported is very close to the value printed out with [WorkingSet64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64?view=net-6.0)